# "Whole" in Datagrid

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I have build a datagrid, but there is a "whole" between the columnheader and the scrollbar.
Is there a way in xaml to put the header over the scrollbar?

screenshot:
http://www.pictureupload.de/originals/pictures/190411124345_grid.JPG

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the style for your DataGrid then you will see the vertical scroll bar defined in the template something like this:

```
<ScrollBar Grid.Row="1"
Grid.Column="2"
Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
Orientation="Vertical"
Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
Value="{Binding Path=VerticalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
```

What you need to do is change the Grid.Row="0" and set Grid.RowSpan="2"